# How to avoid calling StoreModule.forRoot() twice when using ngrx in a library

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am creating an angular library that uses ngrx. For the library I have just a couple Feature reducers that I can initialize easy enough in the library base module. The problem is that I don't know whether or not to call StoreModule.forRoot(...) in the library base module. Some consumers of the library already use ngrx so if I do it will break as it gets called twice however some consumers are not using it so it will break if I don't include it. I could require all consumers who do not already use ngrx to include StoreModule.forRoot([]) in their base module imports but I would like to avoid this. Is there a way to conditionally initialize the store module from the library to avoid these errors?

Comment: Did you find a possible solution for this? Because I am having this same issue.

Comment: Wow didn't think about it this way. Well it's to look at the codebase of ngrx and know how ngrx can identify when forRoot is called twice. If the API is public, then we can detect it in our library. If it has been called, then we call forFeature, else we call forRoot. The issue here is how to access this API from the module imports array